# Download large file and "connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid (...)"

Tags: php, curl, download

I'm trying to download a large file (1.2GB) from webpage. I should be logged when I would like to download any file so first, I'm using curl to get cookies (PHPSESSID) and then I'm trying to download file like this:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename[1]);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . ($filesize[1]*1000000));
header('Pragma: public');

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"Cookie: PHPSESSID=".$phpSesSid)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$handle = fopen($dwn, "r", false, $context);
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And this solution is fine. The file is downloading to ~150MB and then my browser stop download file and get info: "download failed".

I don't know where is a problem. When I look in "error logs" I get this errors:

> [Mon Jan 19 12:27:22 2015] [warn] [client 178.183.xxx] (104)Connection
>   reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
>
> [Mon Jan 19 12:27:22 2015] [warn] [client 178.183.xxx] (104)Connection
>   reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc
>   function
>
> [Mon Jan 19 12:27:22 2015] [error] [client 178.183.xxx] File does not
>   exist: /home/xx/domains/xx.yy.pl/public_html/500.shtml

Where is a problem? Can u help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe that the PHP script is terminated. It's not a good thing to read a file then print it out to a broswer, since a PHP script runs only up to 30 secs. I think you can download 150MB in that time, then the script is terminated by the web server.

You can bypass this by redirect the browser to the actual file, or if you want to hide the real file name and direct link to it, you can create a temporary symlink to that file then redirect your browser to this.

```
$tempfile = rand();
symlink($filename, '/www/downloads/'.$tempfile.$filename);
header('Location: /downloads/'.$tempfile.$filename);
```

And then setup a cron job to unlink the symlinks older than a day or any time you want your download to remain available.